# Auto Populate a lookup field based on Account ID

Tags: apex, controller

I have a custom object 'X' , in which i have a person account field , I want to auto -populate that Account lookup field with account name in page layout from controller...... I am not using any Visualforce Page ..... I am using a HTML Page in front end. and backend we are using apex , we are designing a site in salesforce. This is the code i have written

```
 List <Account> acc = new List <Account>();
      email = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('key');
       system.debug('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'+email);
        acc=[select ID from Account where Personemail = : email Limit 1];
```

Comment: what do you means using html page not visualforce page?

Comment: + to Ratan question. if you are not using vf page where you are using controller. update this question with more details.

Comment: front end we are using HTML  and back end we are coding  in apex ..... we are designing a site in salesforce .

Comment: The `ApexPages.currentPage()` call will only work in the context of Visualforce. Not sure what you mean by "HTML page in front end". Do you mean you are using a Visualforce page with only standard HTML tags?

Comment: yes  front end design we have done with HTML and we have used some of the apex vf methods to relate it to the controller .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have custom account lookup with APi name `account__c` then in your controller just do this.

```
List <Account> acc = new List <Account>();

email = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('key');

system.debug('===================='+email);

acc=[select ID,Name from Account where Personemail = : email Limit 1];

xyz.account__c = acc[0].Id;
```

Here xyz is the object instance which are using in VF page with field binding. It will give you name if you are using inputfield but if you are using some html field then bind

```
xyz.customvariable = acc[0].Name;
```

and show this custom variable on page and bind account field with hidden variable and update your value